# Promoted widgets do not appear in main application created with qt designer

Tags: pyqt5, designer

I'm writting an application composed of several independant widgets to make an experiment running. For example, the aim is to control differents instruments (e. g. a scope, cameras or mechanical shutters).

Each independant widget I created, with Qt Designer and PyQt5 on Linux, work correctly. My idea is now to embed those widgets in a QMainWindow. What I did (and is working well) so far is the following :

- In a QTabWidget, I place a single widget within a tab (three different tabs so three different widgets). I promote each single widget to a class that controls a scope (or a camera). By running the main application, the custom widgets show up correctly and everything runs as expected.

Then, I create the same kind of custom widget inside a QGroupBox object and want to promote to a different class than the ones used before. Same procedure to promote the widget. Now by running, the main application, nothing shows up in the placeholder.

In the .py file corresponding to the main window, all the files corresponding to the classes I want the widgets to be promoted to are well imported.

**So my question is**: Do you have any thoughts about what is going on ?

I try to find some answers on the Internet, looks like it is related to .qrc file and resources. But this is far beyond my knowledges on PyQt and Qt Designer. Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Here is my minimal reproducible example composed of a set of one working widget and one invisible.

main_viewer.py:

```py
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

from ui_main import Ui_MainViewer

from camera_viewer import CameraViewer
from laser import LaserViewer

class MainViewer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        ui = Ui_MainViewer()
        ui.setupUi(self)
        self.main_ui = ui

        # Redefinition of items in the first tab to keep only one
        self.main_ui.andor_widget.ui.ui_camera_cmb.clear()
        self.main_ui.andor_widget.ui.ui_camera_cmb.addItems(["Camera #1"])
        self.main_ui.basler_widget.ui.ui_camera_cmb.clear()
        self.main_ui.basler_widget.ui.ui_camera_cmb.addItems(["Camera #2"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainViewer()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

ui_main.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui_main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainViewer(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainViewer):
        MainViewer.setObjectName("MainViewer")
        MainViewer.resize(1337, 778)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainViewer)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.light_sources_groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.light_sources_groupBox.setObjectName("light_sources_groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.light_sources_groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.red_laser_groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.light_sources_groupBox)
        self.red_laser_groupBox.setObjectName("red_laser_groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.red_laser_groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_5.setObjectName("gridLayout_5")
        self.widget = LaserViewer(self.red_laser_groupBox)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout_5.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.red_laser_groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.green_laser_groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.light_sources_groupBox)
        self.green_laser_groupBox.setObjectName("green_laser_groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.green_laser_groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.widget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.green_laser_groupBox)
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.widget_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.green_laser_groupBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.white_light_groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.light_sources_groupBox)
        self.white_light_groupBox.setObjectName("white_light_groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_15 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.white_light_groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_15.setObjectName("gridLayout_15")
        self.widget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.white_light_groupBox)
        self.widget_3.setObjectName("widget_3")
        self.gridLayout_15.addWidget(self.widget_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.white_light_groupBox, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.light_sources_groupBox, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.gridLayout_13 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab)
        self.gridLayout_13.setObjectName("gridLayout_13")
        self.andor_widget = CameraViewer(self.tab)
        self.andor_widget.setObjectName("andor_widget")
        self.gridLayout_13.addWidget(self.andor_widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.gridLayout_14 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.gridLayout_14.setObjectName("gridLayout_14")
        self.basler_widget = CameraViewer(self.tab_2)
        self.basler_widget.setObjectName("basler_widget")
        self.gridLayout_14.addWidget(self.basler_widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.scope_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tab_3)
        self.scope_widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 741, 631))
        self.scope_widget.setObjectName("scope_widget")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 1, 4, 1)
        self.groupBox_7 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_7.setObjectName("groupBox_7")
        self.gridLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox_7)
        self.gridLayout_8.setObjectName("gridLayout_8")
        self.groupBox_10 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.groupBox_7)
        self.groupBox_10.setObjectName("groupBox_10")
        self.gridLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox_10)
        self.gridLayout_9.setObjectName("gridLayout_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_10)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_10)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.gridLayout_9.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_8.addWidget(self.groupBox_10, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox_8 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.groupBox_7)
        self.groupBox_8.setObjectName("groupBox_8")
        self.gridLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox_8)
        self.gridLayout_10.setObjectName("gridLayout_10")
        self.widget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.groupBox_8)
        self.widget_4.setObjectName("widget_4")
        self.gridLayout_10.addWidget(self.widget_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_8.addWidget(self.groupBox_8, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_7, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        self.widget_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        self.widget_5.setObjectName("widget_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.widget_5)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_2, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        MainViewer.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainViewer)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1337, 20))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainViewer.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainViewer)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainViewer.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainViewer)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainViewer)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainViewer):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainViewer.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainViewer", "Superfluidity experiment"))
        self.light_sources_groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainViewer", "Light sources"))
        self.red_laser_groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainViewer", "Red laser"))
        self.green_laser_groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainViewer", "Green laser"))
        self.white_light_groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainViewer", "White light"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainViewer", "Cameras and Scope"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainViewer", "Camera Andor"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainViewer", "Camera Basler"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainViewer", "Scope"))
        self.groupBox_7.setTitle(_translate("MainViewer", "Aqcuisition"))
        self.groupBox_10.setTitle(_translate("MainViewer", "Images"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainViewer", "Acquire"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainViewer", "Save data"))
        self.groupBox_8.setTitle(_translate("MainViewer", "Filters"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainViewer", "SLM and DMD"))

from camera_viewer import CameraViewer
from laser import LaserViewer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainViewer = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainViewer()
    ui.setupUi(MainViewer)
    MainViewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

camera_viewer.py (widget that works fine)

```py
import numpy as np
import sys
import time
from PIL import Image
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

import pyqtgraph as pg

from ui_camera import Ui_CameraViewer

# to avoid pyqtgraph to crash
MIN_DISPLAY_TIME = 0.03
MAX_FRAME_RATE = 5.


class CameraViewer(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CameraViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        ui = Ui_CameraViewer()
        ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui = ui

        # Connect all ui buttons and initialise default values
        self.ui.ui_exposure_time_dspn.setValue(MIN_DISPLAY_TIME)
        self.ui.ui_frame_rate_dspn.setValue(MAX_FRAME_RATE)
        self.ui.ui_camera_cmb.addItems(["Camera #1", "Camera #2"])
        #TODO make a method for that
        self.ui.ui_live_btn.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_stop_live_btn.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_snapshot_btn.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_exposure_time_dspn.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_frame_rate_dspn.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_exposure_time_label.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_frame_rate_label.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_adjust_level_btn.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_auto_level_chk.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_crosshair_chk.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_save_btn.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_save_params_btn.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.ui_load_params_btn.setDisabled(True)

        # Design of the image display
        # Image
        self.plot_image = self.ui.ui_image.addPlot(name='image', labels={'left': "<span style='color: red'>Y</span> (px)", 'bottom': "<span style='color: yellow'>X</span> (px)"}, colspan=3)
        self.plot_image.setMinimumHeight(200)
        self.view = self.plot_image.vb
        self.view.setAspectLocked(True)
        self.image = pg.ImageItem(border='w')
        self.plot_image.addItem(self.image)

        # X and Y profiles
        self.ui.ui_image.nextRow()
        self.plot_profiles = self.ui.ui_image.addPlot(labels={'left': 'Pixel value', 'bottom': "<span style='color: yellow'>X</span>, <span style='color: red'>Y</span> (px)"}, colspan=3)
        self.plot_profiles.setMaximumHeight(75)
        self.plot_profiles.setXLink('image')

        # Image informations
        self.ui.ui_image.nextRow()
        self.label_prof = self.ui.ui_image.addLabel(justify='left', col=1)
        self.label_prof.setMaximumHeight(25)
        self.label_hist = self.ui.ui_image.addLabel(justify='left', col=2)
        self.label_prof.setMaximumHeight(25)

        # Crosshair
        self.vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False)
        self.hLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False)
        self.index_x = 0
        self.index_y = 0

        self.cam_connected = False
        self.mode_live = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = CameraViewer()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    # main()
```

ui_camera.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui_camera.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_CameraViewer(object):
    def setupUi(self, CameraViewer):
        CameraViewer.setObjectName("CameraViewer")
        CameraViewer.resize(590, 756)
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(CameraViewer)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(CameraViewer)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.ui_image = GraphicsLayoutWidget(self.frame_3)
        self.ui_image.setObjectName("ui_image")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.ui_image, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.ui_adjust_level_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        self.ui_adjust_level_btn.setObjectName("ui_adjust_level_btn")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.ui_adjust_level_btn)
        self.ui_auto_level_chk = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.frame_3)
        self.ui_auto_level_chk.setChecked(True)
        self.ui_auto_level_chk.setObjectName("ui_auto_level_chk")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.ui_auto_level_chk)
        self.ui_crosshair_chk = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.frame_3)
        self.ui_crosshair_chk.setObjectName("ui_crosshair_chk")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.ui_crosshair_chk)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.frame_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(CameraViewer)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.ui_save_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.ui_save_btn.setObjectName("ui_save_btn")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.ui_save_btn)
        self.ui_save_params_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.ui_save_params_btn.setObjectName("ui_save_params_btn")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.ui_save_params_btn)
        self.ui_load_params_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.ui_load_params_btn.setObjectName("ui_load_params_btn")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.ui_load_params_btn)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.frame_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(CameraViewer)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.ui_live_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.ui_live_btn.setObjectName("ui_live_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ui_live_btn, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ui_snapshot_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.ui_snapshot_btn.setObjectName("ui_snapshot_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ui_snapshot_btn, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.ui_stop_live_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.ui_stop_live_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui_stop_live_btn.setObjectName("ui_stop_live_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ui_stop_live_btn, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.ui_exposure_time_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.ui_exposure_time_label.setObjectName("ui_exposure_time_label")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.ui_exposure_time_label)
        self.ui_exposure_time_dspn = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.ui_exposure_time_dspn.setDecimals(3)
        self.ui_exposure_time_dspn.setMinimum(0.03)
        self.ui_exposure_time_dspn.setMaximum(10000.0)
        self.ui_exposure_time_dspn.setSingleStep(0.01)
        self.ui_exposure_time_dspn.setProperty("value", 0.05)
        self.ui_exposure_time_dspn.setObjectName("ui_exposure_time_dspn")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.ui_exposure_time_dspn)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.ui_frame_rate_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.ui_frame_rate_label.setEnabled(True)
        self.ui_frame_rate_label.setObjectName("ui_frame_rate_label")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.ui_frame_rate_label)
        self.ui_frame_rate_dspn = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.ui_frame_rate_dspn.setMinimum(0.0)
        self.ui_frame_rate_dspn.setMaximum(30.0)
        self.ui_frame_rate_dspn.setSingleStep(0.1)
        self.ui_frame_rate_dspn.setProperty("value", 10.0)
        self.ui_frame_rate_dspn.setObjectName("ui_frame_rate_dspn")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.ui_frame_rate_dspn)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3, 4, 1, 1, 2)
        self.ui_disconnect_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.ui_disconnect_btn.setObjectName("ui_disconnect_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ui_disconnect_btn, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.ui_camera_cmb = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.frame)
        self.ui_camera_cmb.setObjectName("ui_camera_cmb")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ui_camera_cmb, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.ui_connect_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.ui_connect_btn.setObjectName("ui_connect_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ui_connect_btn, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(CameraViewer)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(CameraViewer)

    def retranslateUi(self, CameraViewer):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        CameraViewer.setWindowTitle(_translate("CameraViewer", "Form"))
        self.ui_adjust_level_btn.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Ajust level"))
        self.ui_auto_level_chk.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Auto level"))
        self.ui_crosshair_chk.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Crosshair"))
        self.ui_save_btn.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Save image"))
        self.ui_save_params_btn.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Save Params"))
        self.ui_load_params_btn.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Load Params"))
        self.ui_live_btn.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Live mode"))
        self.ui_snapshot_btn.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Snapshot"))
        self.ui_stop_live_btn.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Stop live mode"))
        self.ui_exposure_time_label.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Exposure time (s)"))
        self.ui_frame_rate_label.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Frame rate (Hz)"))
        self.ui_disconnect_btn.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Disconnect"))
        self.ui_connect_btn.setText(_translate("CameraViewer", "Connect"))

from pyqtgraph import GraphicsLayoutWidget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    CameraViewer = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_CameraViewer()
    ui.setupUi(CameraViewer)
    CameraViewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

laser.py (not working widget)

```py
import sys
import serial
import random
import struct
import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from ui_laser import Ui_Laser

class LaserViewer(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LaserViewer, self).__init__(parent)

        # set up of the ui
        self.ui_laser = Ui_Laser()
        self.ui_laser.setupUi(self)

        # Initialization
        self.ui_laser.ui_wavelength_cmb.addItems(["Green", "Red"])
        self.ui_laser.pwr_doubleSpinBox.value()

        self.picoscope_connected = False
        self.laser_id = 'green'

        self.ui_laser.laser_on_pushButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui_laser.laser_off_pushButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui_laser.pwr_doubleSpinBox.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui_laser.power_value_lineEdit.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui_laser.continuous_slow_right_pushButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui_laser.continuous_slow_left_pushButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui_laser.laser_disconnect_pushButton.setDisabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window1 = LaserViewer()
    window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    # main()
```

ui_laser.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui_laser.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Laser(object):
    def setupUi(self, Laser):
        Laser.setObjectName("Laser")
        Laser.resize(559, 75)
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Laser)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.laser_off_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Laser)
        self.laser_off_pushButton.setObjectName("laser_off_pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.laser_off_pushButton, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pwr_doubleSpinBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(Laser)
        self.pwr_doubleSpinBox.setObjectName("pwr_doubleSpinBox")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pwr_doubleSpinBox, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.ui_wavelength_cmb = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Laser)
        self.ui_wavelength_cmb.setObjectName("ui_wavelength_cmb")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ui_wavelength_cmb, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.laser_on_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Laser)
        self.laser_on_pushButton.setObjectName("laser_on_pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.laser_on_pushButton, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Laser)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_5, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Laser)
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_6, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.power_value_lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Laser)
        self.power_value_lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.power_value_lineEdit.setObjectName("power_value_lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.power_value_lineEdit, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Laser)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 5, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Laser)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 5, 1, 1)
        self.continuous_slow_right_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Laser)
        self.continuous_slow_right_pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(22, 22))
        self.continuous_slow_right_pushButton.setObjectName("continuous_slow_right_pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.continuous_slow_right_pushButton, 0, 7, 1, 1)
        self.continuous_slow_left_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Laser)
        self.continuous_slow_left_pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(22, 22))
        self.continuous_slow_left_pushButton.setObjectName("continuous_slow_left_pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.continuous_slow_left_pushButton, 0, 6, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.laser_connect_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Laser)
        self.laser_connect_pushButton.setObjectName("laser_connect_pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.laser_connect_pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.laser_disconnect_pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Laser)
        self.laser_disconnect_pushButton.setObjectName("laser_disconnect_pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.laser_disconnect_pushButton, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Laser)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Laser)

    def retranslateUi(self, Laser):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Laser.setWindowTitle(_translate("Laser", "Laser control"))
        self.laser_off_pushButton.setText(_translate("Laser", "Close shutter"))
        self.laser_on_pushButton.setText(_translate("Laser", "Open shutter"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Laser", "Power setting"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Laser", "Power on PD"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Laser", "µW"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Laser", "µW"))
        self.continuous_slow_right_pushButton.setText(_translate("Laser", ">"))
        self.continuous_slow_left_pushButton.setText(_translate("Laser", "<"))
        self.laser_connect_pushButton.setText(_translate("Laser", "Connect"))
        self.laser_disconnect_pushButton.setText(_translate("Laser", "Disconnect"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Laser = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Laser()
    ui.setupUi(Laser)
    Laser.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you for your help and sorry for the length of the question...

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Did you set a layout on the group-box?

Comment: Each group box has a layout but widget within the group box doesn't.

Comment: Your `LaserViewer` class inherits from `QDialog` which means that `LaserViewer` widgets will be shown as a window by default even if they have a parent. To embed them into your main window, you could try making it a subclass of `QWidget` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out bu Heike, the problem comes from the parent class of `LaserViewer`. By inheriting from `QWidget` instead of `QDialog` fixes the problem.

Thank you very much for pointing this out!